# How to get the expected output?

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(C.DATE_SK),'YYYY-MM-DD'),'MON'), 
    A.PRODUCT, 
    c.REG_HOURS + c.OFF_HOURS 
FROM 
    DIM_PRODUCT A 
INNER JOIN 
    DIM_TICKET B ON A.PRODUCT_SK = B.PRODUCT_SK 
INNER JOIN 
    FACT_TIMESHEET C ON C.TICKET_SK = B.TICKET_SK 
GROUP BY   
    A.PRODUCT, c.REG_HOURS + c.OFF_HOURS,
    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(C.DATE_SK),'YYYY-MM-DD'),'MON');
```

My output is like:

```
+------------------------------------------------+
| col1(month)   col2(product name)   col3(hours) |
+------------------------------------------------+
| mar             aaa                 1          |
| mar             aaa                 2          |
| mar             aaa                 3          |
| apr             bbb                 2.5        |
| apr             bbb                 3          |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

My expected output is like:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| col1(month)   col2(product name)  col3(hours) |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| mar           aaa                  6          |
| apr           bbb                  5.5        |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT A.MONTH, A.PRODUCT_NAME, SUM(A.HOURS)
FROM (YOUR QUERY) A
GROUP BY A.MONTH, A.PRODUCT_NAME;
```

Comment: I'm getting some null values.I don't know the reason.But your query works Yasuyuki